# Maven cannot exec a jar project because the mess with transitive dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven-2, orm

I have 5 maven projects: `simple-model`, `simple-weather`, `simple-persist`, `simple-webapp` and `simple-console`. (They are from the Maven Definitive Guide book).
The `simple-console` depends on `simple-weather` and `simple-persist`. `simple-persist` and `simple-weather` both depend on `simple-model`:

```
simple-console ---> simple-weather ----> simple-model
             \                       /
              \---> simple-persist--/
```

`simple-console` depends on `spring` and `hibernate`, in effect depends on a jar that contains `javax.transaction.TransactionManager`.
I generate eclipse projects for these 5 projects.
The `Main` class inside `simple-console` (which invoke a Hibernate method) run fine in eclipse.
However, when I tried to execute it with `Maven`'s`exec:java` goal or `java -cp` (assemblied with `jar-with-dependencies`), I always got this error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager`

It really confused me because, while eclipse knows how to include necessary jars before execution, maven plugins don't make sense of that.
Why?

P/S: I have uploaded the source code of these projects here:
http://seamoo.com/simple-parent.tar.gz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `mvn dependency:tree` in *simple-console*, you won't see the JTA artifact:

```
[INFO] org.seamoo:simple-console:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.seamoo:simple-persist:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seamoo:simple-model:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO] +- org.seamoo:simple-weather:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] \- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:compile
```

And indeed, if you look at `simple-persist/pom.xml`, you'll see that it has been excluded:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

My guess is that the jta artifact is excluded because the full hibernate jar (`hibernate-3.2.5.ga.jar` here) depends on `jta-1.0.1B.jar` which is **NOT** available in the central repo due to licensing issues while hibernate core (i.e. `hibernate-core-3.3.0.GA.jar`) depends on `jta-1.1.jar`, which is available from central.

The reason why it works in Eclipse is that the *simple-model* depends on `hibernate-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar` which depends on `hibernate-3.2.1.GA.jar` which depends on `jta-1.0.1B.jar` (that you very likely have in your local repository). So, because the whole hibernate dependencies are a big mess in this project, because there are big dependencies convergences problems, Eclipse "sees" the JTA jar (that's just a fortunate or unfortunate side effect). But Maven doesn't.

To solve the problem, either remove the JTA exclusion in `simple-persist/pom.xml` (that's the quick and very dirty fix) or fix the hibernate dependencies to make them converge (that would be the right fix):

- use `hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar` wherever required
- use `hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar` (which depends on the former) wherever required

Comment: You are so right. It amazes me how did you figure the problem out. You're a genius.